# i had problem with selenium x path i make Facebook sharing script but he is not clicking share how can i fix this? i'm using python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, selenium-chromedriver

I had a problem with Facebook share button when I execute that it's doing all good but it's not clicking on facebook share button please help me!

Here is my video you can see here>> https://photos.app.goo.gl/Pi1tRQTwhqg5tmpn9

here is element HTML code:

here is this element code :

```
<span class="_18vi"><a class=" _2nj7 _18vj _18vk" data-ft="{ &quot;tn&quot;: &quot;J&quot;, &quot;type&quot;: 25 }" href="/ajax/sharer/?s=22&amp;appid=25554907596&amp;id=1816791348467451&amp;p[0]=130584170421519&amp;p[1]=1816792805133972&amp;sharer_type=all_modes&amp;av=130584170421519" rel="dialog" role="button" tabindex="0" title="Send this to friends or post it on your timeline.">Share</a></span>
```

Here is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time


driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.facebook.com/")
driver.maximize_window()
phone=WebDriverWait(driver, 50).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='email']"))).send_keys("03460522942")
time.sleep(2)
pas=WebDriverWait(driver, 50).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='pass']"))).send_keys("......")
time.sleep(.5)
login=WebDriverWait(driver, 50).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='loginbutton']"))).click()
time.sleep(.5)
#Searc
search=WebDriverWait(driver, 100).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "/html[1]/body[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/form[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/input[2]"))).send_keys("lunch.pk")
search2=WebDriverWait( driver, 100).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "/html[1]/body[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/form[1]/button[1]"))).click()
click_page=WebDriverWait( driver, 50).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "/html[1]/body[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/a[1]/span[1]"))).click()
click_photos=WebDriverWait( driver, 50).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "/html[1]/body[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div[3]"))).click()
click_banner=WebDriverWait( driver, 50).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "/html[1]/body[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/a[1]/img[1]"))).click()
click_Share=WebDriverWait( driver, 50).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='u_1b_2']/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/span[3]/a/text()"))).click()
```

Here is my error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\facebook.py", line 24, in <module>
    click_Share=WebDriverWait( driver, 50).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='u_1b_2']/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/span[3]/a/text()"))).click()
  File "C:\Users\Hamza Lachi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 71, in until
    value = method(self._driver)
  File "C:\Users\Hamza Lachi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\expected_conditions.py", line 297, in __call__
    element = visibility_of_element_located(self.locator)(driver)
  File "C:\Users\Hamza Lachi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\expected_conditions.py", line 128, in __call__
    return _element_if_visible(_find_element(driver, self.locator))
  File "C:\Users\Hamza Lachi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\expected_conditions.py", line 148, in _element_if_visible

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'is_displayed'
```

Iמ

```
return element if element.is_displayed() == visibility else False
```

Comment: could you also paste the HTML for this element please?

Comment: okay! here is this element code :  <span class="_18vi"><a class=" _2nj7  _18vj _18vk" data-ft="{ &quot;tn&quot;: &quot;J&quot;, &quot;type&quot;: 25 }" href="/ajax/sharer/?s=22&amp;appid=25554907596&amp;id=1816791348467451&amp;p[0]=130584170421519&amp;p[1]=1816792805133972&amp;sharer_type=all_modes&amp;av=130584170421519" rel="dialog" role="button" tabindex="0" title="Send this to friends or post it on your timeline.">Share</a></span>

Comment: Here is my video you can see here>> https://photos.app.goo.gl/Pi1tRQTwhqg5tmpn9

Comment: @HamzaMirchi It's difficult to read html code from comments, kindly update in the question.

Comment: @SRM21 I updated Please Check And Help Me plz!

Comment: @HamzaMirchi its not a button. Please search for the button in DOM and update the question with correct HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested your issue(on MacOS Mojave) and was successful in clicking the share button on facebook:
solution: use two clicks when your code executes `click_Share`

```
click_Share=WebDriverWait( driver, 50).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='u_1b_2']/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/span[3]/a/text()"))).click()
click_Share=WebDriverWait( driver, 50).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='u_1b_2']/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/span[3]/a/text()"))).click()
```

I think the issue might be some facebook related one-off issue. Should be only need one click for clickable elements on most sites.

### UPDATED ANSWER:

You also might be grabbing wrong XPATH, replace your line of code:

```
click_Share=WebDriverWait( driver, 50).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='u_1b_2']/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/span[3]/a/text()"))).click()
```

with this line:

```
click_Share=WebDriverWait( driver, 50).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='u_g_2']/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/span[3]"))).click()
```

### Also note:

Facebook might be dynamically creating new XPATHs whenever the user uploads an image so maybe if the CSS_SELECTOR is static for location the button that method should be used instead of XPATH

Comment: let me try in my case he is not clicking let me try a double-time Thanks!

Comment: I understand user is **not double-click** but this is the solution that works for getting desired result.

Comment: bro still not working is this script work on your pc?

Comment: Which Browser You use?

Comment: I am using chrome. I can try on a windows 10 when I get home.

Comment: Please Check And Tell Me plzz

Answer (score 0):

Try with javascriptExecutor

```
shareButton= driver.find_element_by_xpath("//your/xpath/here//")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", shareButton)
```

Comment: please share the trace

Comment: File ".\facebook.py", line 24, in <module>
    shareButton= driver.find_element_by_xpath("///*[@id='u_g_2']/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/span[3]")
  File "C:\Users\Hamza Lachi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 394, in find_element_by_xpath
    return self.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value=xpath)